# Avoiding corrupting JSON during save to file in case of power outages

Tags: python, json

I have built a tkinter application that automatically saves data to a `json` file every 30 seconds. One of my users had to unfortunate experience of a power outage while the application was running, and it just so happened to coincide with a call to the `save_to_file` function, resulting in a corrupted save file missing half the cached data and lost quite a bit of the brackets in the json as well. I could manually restore the json such that it was readable again, but the data has been lost forever.

Is there any way to avoid situations like these in case of future power outages?

I have put together a small sample from my code that imitates the autosave function I have built

```py
def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.root = tk.Tk()
    self.save_to_file()
    ...

def save_to_file(self):
    with open(self.file_path, 'w') as fo:
        json.dump(self.cache, fo, indent=2) # self.cache is a dict
    self.root.after(30000, self.save_to_file)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write to a temporary file, then rename it to the permanent name.

Renaming is atomic, so if there's an outage the permanent file will be either the old version or new version, but never a partial file.

```
import os 

def save_to_file(self):
    with open(self.file_path + ".tmp", 'w') as fo:
        json.dump(self.cache, fo, indent=2)
    os.rename(self.file_path + ".tmp", self.file_path)
    self.root.after(30000, self.save_to_file)
```

Comment: this method has also the advantage of not performing too much disk io. Most serious applications use it. BTW you should try to `os.remove` the destination file, as some OSes may refuse to rename over an existing file

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre but the same disk io will be performed, just on the temp file instead of the actual file, no?

Comment: it's important that the temp file resides on the same filesystem, or rename won't be atomic.

Comment: (BTW, I don't recommend always adding `.tmp` as a constant suffix -- if doing that, two programs trying to write to that same .tmp file at the same time can cause corrupt output to be created; it's better to use facilities like Python's `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` or the lower-level `tempfile.mkstemp` that generate a random, unique name).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It's in the same directory, so it must be on the same filesystem.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy In this case I think it's a safe assumption that there's only  one instance of this, otherwise they'd run into the same collision problem with the original code.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Barmar is right to use a .tmp prefix. Using a temp file on another filesystem makes rename not atomic, and if a power outage occurs when the file is copied, then the source AND the destination are lost (temp files are flushed on reboot). Most serious IDEs do that. Including emacs and vi

Comment: @Barmar, true; but as with every SO question, the intended audience extends beyond the OP.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, pardon? How could my suggestion _possibly_ be interpreted as advising that the temporary file be in a different directory or filesystem? I'm only advising that it have a unique, randomly-generated **suffix**, as `tempfile.mkstemp` will do automatically.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Doesn't `mkstemp` use `/tmp`?

Comment: @Barmar, by default, but that can and should be overridden.

Comment: it could, by people who read too fast, like me. Aside, the destination file must be removed if exists before renaming occurs.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, ...pardon? `os.rename()` on any inode-based, POSIX-y filesystem has no such requirement. There _is_ potentially a need to force a flush-to-disk of the directory itself before and after the rename, so I'll grant that just switching to mkstemp isn't sufficient to make things safe against power loss (as opposed to process shutdown with the kernel still surviving), but doing a separate unlink before the rename merely compromises atomicity with no benefit.

Comment: ...anyhow, there are enough details here that need to be gotten right to be completely safe that I think this is a good candidate for relying on longer-standing, canonical instances of the question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy on windows `os.rename` fails if the destination exists. To be portable, the code must try to delete the destination (I just made the test). In that case maybe `shutil.move` is a better choice

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, to be sure, Windows is a different kettle of fish (there's a reason I edited my above comment to specify POSIX-flavored filesystems only). _Unconditionally_ doing the Windows-friendly thing creates more failure cases on UNIX-y systems, so it's not a good idea to do across the board.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the data to a temporary/backup file, then overwrite the save location with the temporary file. In this way, you can keep the data from the previous save (60 seconds ago) while only losing the previous 30 seconds if a power outage / crash happens.